# Android: How can I check a particular item in a Checked ListView?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, checkedtextview

I am using a ListView in which only one item can be checked at a time. 
This is my custom list_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    />
```

I populate the list in onCreate() using a normal array adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, strings);
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

When the list is displayed, I want to have, say, the 5th item in the list appear as Checked. How can I go about doing this? I know CheckedTextView has a function called setChecked(), but how can I get my 5th item from the list to apply this function on it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Referring another answer in StackOverflow, I have found that the simplest way to achieve this is using

```
myList.setItemChecked(pos, true);
```

Here you can find the actual thread : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556764/programatically-access-specific-rows-in-list-of-checkedtextviews-android)